# programming in linux bash, my program does not respond

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu

im working in linux bash, and i have a problem, im doing a exercise what say this:
"will ask for three strings by keyboard and will test
whether three valid texts have been entered or whether
these strings correspond to directory names.
If so, list what is inside each one
of them and show it. If no three have been entered
strings or any of the three is not a directory,
display a warning indicating the error." okey, in my code, i ask the strings and then, as you can see in each if, I am comparing if they correspond to a directory name or not. **However, the bash gives me an error on the line. option_4.sh: line 52: syntactic error: the end of the file was not expected.**

```
    #!/bin/bash

echo "Ask for three string from keyboard";
read -p "Give me a string:" string1;
read -p "Give me another string:" string2;
read -p "Give another string:" string3;

if [ -d "$string1" ];
cd "$directorio"

if [ -d "$string1" ];
then
  echo ""
  echo "The cadena1 is the name of a directory.."
  echo "His content ($string1):"

  ls ./"$string1"
else
  echo "ERROR: The cadena1 does not correspond to the name of a directory."
fi


if [ -d "$string2" ];
cd "$directorio"

if [ -d "$string2" ];
then
  echo ""
  echo "The cadena2 is the name of a directory."
  echo "His content ($string2):"

  ls ./"$string2"
else
  echo "ERROR: The cadena2 does not correspond to the name of a directory."
fi


if [ -d "$string3" ];
cd "$directorio"

if [ -d "$string3" ];
then
  echo ""
  echo "The cadena3 is the name of a directory."
  echo "His content ($string3):"

  ls ./"$string3"
else
  echo "ERROR: The cadena1 does not correspond to the name of a directory."
fi
```

Comment: Paste your script at https://shellcheck.net for validation.

Comment: Many thanks!, I did not know this validation tool, very useful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax of an if statement looks like this:

```
if [ <some test> ]
then
<commands>
else
<commands>
fi
```

[source (edited)](https://ryanstutorials.net/bash-scripting-tutorial/bash-if-statements.php)

You need to change the first of the two if statements per string to

```
if [ -d "$string1" ];
then
cd "$directorio";
fi
```

Or even combine the two checks, because the next check has the same condition:

```
if [ -d "$string1" ];
then
  cd "$directorio" # moved here
  echo ""
  echo "The cadena1 is the name of a directory.."
  echo "His content ($string1):"

  ls ./"$string1"
else
  echo "ERROR: The cadena1 does not correspond to the name of a directory."
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

just choose a snippet to describe it, I am not sure whether you want to use absolute path or relative path. so in your script use `pushd` and `popd` will be more convenient.

and if you want to add condition check in your script, you need add `then` after the keyword `if`, and at the end you need add keyword `fi`

```
if [ -d "$string3" ];
cd "$directorio"

if [ -d "$string3" ]; then
  pushd "$directorio"
  echo ""
  echo "The cadena3 is the name of a directory."
  echo "His content ($string3):"

  ls ./"$string3"
  popd
else
  echo "ERROR: The cadena1 does not correspond to the name of a directory."
fi
```